# How to declare array as a data member of a class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Hello all I am working in javascript and html5.I want to ask that how can we add an array as a data member of a class in javascript
I have written a code

```
var bm =  new Bitmap(img); //It is a built in class of some library

/*Here what I want is to associate an array with object of bitmap*/
/* what i did is */
 var lpr = new Array();
 bm.lpr[0]= "xyz" ;
 bm.lpr[1]= "pqr" ;
```

but when I displayed the array.

```
alert(bm.lpr[0]);
```

I got the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined

can any one please tell me the correct way of doing it.Also my array will be update at run time

Thanks

Comment: your bm variable has no lpr property, they are two different variables. I am not sure what are you trying to do...

Comment: Yes it has not but can add any property of data member to it

Comment: sure but you need to initialize that property in bm variable before you try to access its members...

Comment: Hmmm i am initilizing it.am I doing it wrong

Comment: yes you initialize lpr variable, but that doesnt make it bm's property. You should do `bm.lpr = lpr` before your alert...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to change one line:

```
 var bm =  new Bitmap(img);

 bm.lpr = new Array(); //this is the line you need to change
 bm.lpr[0]= "xyz" ;
 bm.lpr[1]= "pqr" ;


 alert(bm.lpr[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a property of the `bm` instance to hold an array, you can do that like so...

```
bm.lpr = ['xyz', 'pqr'];
```

Your `alert()` will then show what you want.

Comment: instead of `bm.lpr` assignments, do on `lpr` only and in the end update the `bm` object `bm.lpr = lpr`

Comment: `bm.lpr` has to be an `Array` before you can add items to that array; otherwise, you're trying to add items to `undefined`.  If you don't want to initialize the values of the array at the beginning, you can write `bm.lpr = []`, and then you can `push` items into that array later on.